# Python code error when reloading map

Tags: qgis, python, error, windows, mapping

I'm receiving a Python Error when i try to reload a map i am working on, anyone with an idea how to solve this?

```
WARNING    Traceback (most recent call last):
              File "C:/Users/Helfer/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\ale\advanced_line_editor.py", line 299, in currentLayerChanged
              self.currentlayer.editingStarted.disconnect(self.curLayerIsEditable)
             RuntimeError: wrapped C/C++ object of type QgsVectorLayer has been deleted
```

Running QGIS 3.6.0 Noosa Windows 10

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by an installed plugin.

Uninstall the Advanced Line Editor Plugin, if you are not using it.

If you really need it, please file an issue in the [ALE plugin issue tracker](https://github.com/lwiniwar/ALE/issues).